# Node.js Promise - Shouldn't code wait until .then is complete()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am confused by this async behavior.

When `token` is `false`, `refreshToken()` function runs but the `createTokenFile()` doesn't wait for it to finish.

Shouldn't `var tokenDate = new Date(token.expires);` wait after `callApiToken().then(function() {refreshToken();})` to finish before executing?

```
function createTokenFile() {
    console.log("No token-file.json file found. " .red +
            "Please complete for a new one." .red);
    return callApiToken().then(function() {
        refreshToken();
    });
}


function checkExpiredToken() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (!token) {
            refreshToken();
        }
        var tokenDate = new Date(token.expires);
        var utc = new Date().toUTCString();
        var now  = new Date(utc);
 }


 function refreshToken() {
        try {
            var tokenFile = path.join(__dirname, 'token-file.json');
                console.log(tokenFile);
            return token = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(tokenFile, {encoding: 'utf-8'}));
        } catch (err) {
            if (err.code !== 'ENOENT') {
                throw err;
            } else {
                return createTokenFile();
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATED with `refreshToken()`

Comment: What is the relationship between checkExpiredToken` and `createTokenFile`?

Comment: No - that's why it's called "asynchronous". (It's a little hard to tell because it doesn't look like you posted all of your code; where's "refreshToken"? What calls "createTokenFile" and when/where?)

Comment: `return aGlobalVariableThatINeverReference = theActualValueI wantedToReturn` seems silly. Why `return token = ....`?

Comment: just trouble shooting... I was going to take it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't `var tokenDate = new Date(token.expires);` wait after `callApiToken().then(function() {refreshToken();})` to finish before executing?

No - it's not in a `.then()` callback that would wait for the promise to resolve. It only waits until the promise is created - but the promise resolution (that you call "finish") is asynchronous. Notice that promises are not magic, they're [just callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572).

To fix your code,

- in `createTokenFile` you need to `return` the `refreshToken()` from the `then` callback
- `checkExpiredToken` should [not use the `Promise` constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)
- `refreshToken` should *always* return a promise
- there's no reason why `refreshToken` would read the file synchronously
- you shouldn't cache the `token` as a global variable containing the value

```
function createTokenFile() {
    console.log("No token-file.json file found. " +
                "Please complete for a new one.");
    return callApiToken();
}

function checkExpiredToken() {
    return (tokenPromise || refreshToken())
    .then(function(token) {
        var tokenDate = new Date(token.expires);
        var utc = new Date().toUTCString();
        var now = new Date();
    });
}

function refreshToken() {
    var tokenFile = path.join(__dirname, 'token-file.json');
    console.log(tokenFile);
    return tokenPromise = readFileAsync(tokenFile, {encoding: 'utf-8'}))
    .then(JSON.parse)
    .catch(function(err) {
        if (err.code !== 'ENOENT') {
            throw err;
        } else {
            return createTokenFile().then(refreshToken);
        }
    });
}
```

(where `readFileAsync` is a [promisified](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) version of `fs.readFile`)

Comment: Without using a `Promise constructor` can I send a reject on the catch? I tried reject() on the else block in catch but promise still acted as resolved.

Comment: Why would you want to call `reject`? You can simply `throw` or `return` from a promise callback.

Answer (score 2):

Promise do not *de-synchronize* code. An function that is *asynchronous* will always be so. Therefore if `refreshToken` is asynchronous then it's use above will not wait for it to complete before moving on.

Your code sample leaves too much to the imagination (not to mention syntactically incorrect) so a better answer is not available. Perhaps try recreating the situation in jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net.

Comment: `callApiToken` is asynchronous because it returns a promise.

Comment: `checkExpiredToken` is asynchronous because it returns a promise.

Comment: Is ` refreshToken` async just because it calls `createTokenFile` which has `callApiToken().then()`? Other than that I don't see what is making `refreshToken` async

Comment: @dman: All functions execute synchronous, and return immediately. Some of the *start* asynchronous tasks, like your `refreshToken` did. If a function allows us to observe the result of this async operation, we call it `async`. This happens usually by either taking a callback argument or by returning a promise.

Comment: When `callApiToken` is called it immediately returns a promise. Hence it is async. `refreshToken` in turn calls `callApiToken` which returns immediately. Yet your code assumes that `refreshToken` executes synchronously which isn't true. Check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ that explains the event loop.